# I want to learn all about money, business models so that I can reshape my future startup into global tech giant?

Tags: investment-strategies, start-up

I'm currently 17 years old. I have a very brilliant idea of doing some startup in the future and I do believe I can really take it to a global level. But most often than not what I see in the world is there is less value for skills nowadays. Smartest engineers can build coolest of products but the leverage goes to  some other person. I do not want the same to happen with me. So I want to know each and everything regarding stock markets, investment, how to manage companies(or let's just say how to register the company first), business models and so on. Till now I also do not know how to open a bank account and do necessary transactions(that's my skill level right now).But I am enough confident that I can learn all these things on my own. Could anyone please guide me what shall I read (books or sites) so that I can quench my thirst?

Comment: Be careful biting off more than you can chew. Basically you are asking to learn 'all of finance' as well as 'all of programming' and 'all of management'. Your suspicion that being a good engineer won't give you 100% of a company's money is correct - because everything else that goes on to run a company also needs competent people, and they also need a salary. Individuals who provide the funding to pay all those people's salaries until the company makes a profit, also earn money for the risk they take on to provide that capital. All of this isn't something a single person can take on.

Comment: My personal suggestion is if you are 17, and you can afford a formal education from an institution with a good track record of placing graduates with employment, without too much debt, do it. If that isn't possible (or perhaps even if it is) look for job training around you in careers that are in demand, to secure future employment. Build up your skills over time, and if you have an idea for a startup, perhaps you can work on it outside of work, or perhaps you can save enough to quit your job to take a chance (or if you can live with parents etc., perhaps you can do that for longer).

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations on your idea and I hope you can turn it into some market value.  Your tone suggests it is very innovative.  If it was me, I would do two things:

1. Read **The Lean Startup**
2. Start

In this book you will learn strategies on the quickest way to bring your product to market.  Additionally you may want to read **The Myths of Innovation** in this book you will learn that for truly innovative products, you will have more issue with people accepting your idea rather than stealing it.

No one person makes a great company, it takes a team of people.  For example Amazon.  While Jeff Bezos reaped the majority of the profits many engineers, accountants and other disciplines made enough money to change their family tree forever.

Even middle class families hire accountants, lawyers, lawn care, and house keeping in order to build their team and have their life run smoothly.  Given your level of knowledge in some areas of business, you will need a lot of help.  However, that is kind of normal.  Accepting that you will need help to build and run your business is a key to success.  Rewarding those people with the ability to share in the profits will motivate some very talented people.

The key to starting now is that you will likely make very many mistakes.  Learning to overcome those mistakes is a key to the success of your business.

Comment: +1 for "you will learn that for truly innovative products, you will have more issue with people accepting your idea rather than stealing it." ideas are a dime a dozen, it's all about the implementation/execution of them.